# Bulk INSERTs from multiple hosts preformace optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have 15 Amazon AWS EC2 t1.micro inctances which simultaneusly populate Amazon RDS MySQL d2.m2.xlarge database with data using large `INSERTs` (40000 rows in query).

The queries are send continuously. The table is INNODB, two INT columns, there is index for both columns. CPU Utilization of RDS instance is about 30% during data receiving.

When I have one EC2 instance, the speed is in orders faster then I run 15 instances simultaneusly. And the 15-instances group work slower and slower until the speed becomes totally unsatisfactory.

How can I optimize performance of this process?

UPD: 
My `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `UserData` (
 `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`data`),
 KEY `uid` (`uid`),
 KEY `data` (`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need 2 indexes cause it is nessecary for me to fetch data by `uid` and by `data` value.

I insert data with `INSERT INTO UserData (uid, data) VALUES (1,2),(1,3),(1,10),...` with 40000 `(uid,data)` pairs.

15 parallel instances insert ~121 000 000 rows in 2 hours, but I am sure that it can be much more faster.

Comment: You are probably running into locks and IO waits. Is there any possibility that you can create indexes after the rows are inserted?

Comment: I am inserting very large amounts of data, hundreds of Gb. How long will it take to create indexes afterwards?

Comment: If you are doing what you are doing now, the indexes get updated after each insert. As your table gets larger, these index updates take more time to complete as data may have to be resorted/rewirtten. If you can drop your indexes and add them at the end, then it will create the indexes in one shot. The indexes will still likely take a large amount of time to complete, but less than it would if you are updating after each insert.

Comment: @datasage So you meen using `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;` before bulk insertion?

Answer (score 0):

i can sense problem in these of areas :

Point 1) t1.micro is burst instance and it is usually good for spikey compute workloads. Since you had mentioned you will be using it continuously for DB queries/transactions, it can show reduced overall performance. Please change the instance type to better predictable ones.

Point 2) m2.xlarge and t1.micro comes with limited NW bandwidth capacity. In case if the volume of data (in MB/sec) you are transacting/querying with DB is above the NW bandwidth capacity then also you can observe reduced throughput. Imagine if 15 t1.micro are trying to push 100MB/sec , it could be more than the NW pipe that exists between t1.micros and DB instance type

Comment: So the idea is to divide my MySQL server into several ones and thus to balance the traffic?

Comment: And about point 1: when the only one t1.micro is runinng, it pushes data very quikly into database.